# Unity Error When adding Facebook SDK - CommandInvokationFailure Failed to re-package resources

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I get this error when building for android in Unity:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages 

android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.facebook.android:com.facebook.applinks:com.facebook.common:com.facebook.core:com.facebook.login:com.facebook.messenger:com.facebook.places:com.facebook.share -S
```

PS: I Got this error only after adding the facebook sdk to my unity project

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? It's been over a week now, I can't find anything that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look for duplicated libraries.

Sometimes one plugin will add some libraries and another will add the same libraries (in some cases with a different version).

For example, in my project; Mapbox added some libraries (v25.1.0) that my project already had (v25.3.1). When I was making the build I got the same error.

I had to look for those duplicated libraries and remove them. This was the result:

[image: Removing duplicated libraries]

---

So, You should look for the name of the libraries that are causing problems (without the version), and you probably will see the duplicated files. Try to keep the highest version and try to make the build.

Answer (score 0):

- Update Java SdK
- Update Android SdK
- Check target in menifest file and Unity editor. Both should be same.
- Remove duplicate .jar or .aar under plugins folder if there are any.

Comment: will try that and get back to you